# Getting .htaccess to allow access for specified IP, but request .htpasswd user + password if from any other IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

Ive got a site that im trying to set an .htaccess / .htpasswd password restriction on, but at the same time allow any users with a specific IP address access.

So far ive implemented this as below in my .htaccess file, but for some reason this dosnt work, if i visit the site, no matter from which IP address it allows access, if i comment out the line `order deny,allow` above the `Allow from 192.87.22.18` line, the password protection works, but will request an IP from everyone, even if visiting from the `192.87.22.18` IP (note - not my real IP)

(I haven't published my .htpasswd file for obvious reasons, but it is 1 line containing 1 hashed password)

Any ideas ?

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|.htpasswd)$">
    deny from all
    </Files>

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.example\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    order deny,allow

    <Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|.htpasswd)$">
    deny from all
    </Files>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/subdomains/example/httpdocs/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    require valid-user 
    order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.87.22.18
    # satisfy any

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives in htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen yes, but its only to do with the php config so i didint include it in the above, this is what it is : `RemoveType .php
 AddHandler application/php5-fcgi php
 Action application/php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php5fcgi.fcgi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through trial and error i ended up using the below which works on apache 2.0, taken from here : https://perishablepress.com/htaccess-password-protection-tricks/

In the above article they wrapped the code block in `<IfModule mod_auth.c>`
 which was causing the code not to run (as i guess the if block equated to false on this server) so i removed them.

```
    # password protect excluding specific ip
 AuthName "Username and password required"
 AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
 AuthType Basic
 Require valid-user
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 111.222.333.444
 Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 2):

4 you should use:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile c:/wamp/www/_test/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"

<RequireAny>
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

`order`, `deny`, `allow` are now Deprecated.

Comment: thanks, but that ends up giving a server error, do you know what the mimimum spec of LAMP is required to run the above ?